# IDirectSound8 SetCooperativeLevel Returning Incorrect Parameter

Tags: c++, directsound

I have implemented a direct sound class based off a [tutorial](http://www.rastertek.com/dx10tut14.html) but have run into issues when testing it. I have traced the error to IDirectSound8::SetCooperativeLevel which is returning with an error.

Here is a snipit of my DirectSound Initialization method

```
HRESULT r;
DSBUFFERDESC bufferDesc;
WAVEFORMATEX wavFormat;

r = DirectSoundCreate8(NULL, &DSound, NULL);
if (FAILED(r))
{
    _com_error error(r);
    LPCTSTR errText = error.ErrorMessage();
    OutputDebugString(errText);
    return false;
}
OutputDebugStringA("\nCOMPLETE: DSound Stage 1 ");

r = DSound->SetCooperativeLevel(hwnd, DSSCL_PRIORITY);
if (FAILED(r))
{
    _com_error error(r);
    LPCTSTR errText = error.ErrorMessage();
    OutputDebugString(errText);
    return false;
}
OutputDebugStringA("\nCOMPLETE: DSound Stage 2 ");
```

The program gets past my "DSound Stage 1" but fails at `r = DSound->SetCooperativeLevel(hwnd, DSSCL_PRIORITY);`stating "The parameter is incorrect."

At this point I do not know why this error is occurring or how to fix it. I assume that the issue lies with the HWND parameter that I am passing in, but again I do not know if that is at fault or not.

Could this issue be caused by a physical window not being created on runtime? By that I mean when I compile this project there is no window generated- although it looks as though there should be.

Here is the Main.cpp where the HWND is set that I send to my audio class, it is worth noting that I did not write this file and do not fully understand if it should be creating a window or not.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>

#include "RenderEngine.h"
#include "Timer.h"
#include "Audio.h"

//WindowProc function prototype
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, 
                        UINT message, 
                        WPARAM wParam, 
                        LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance,        //Handle to and Instance, This is how windows keeps track of which program is which.
                HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,    //Handle to the Previous Instance, this is a backwards compatibility requirement
                LPSTR lpCmdLine,            //This is a Long Pointer to a string that contains the command line creating the application.
                int nShowCmd)               //This determines what the window will look like.
{
//First we create our Handle for the Window
HWND hWnd;
//Next we create our WindowClass Struct
WNDCLASSEX wc;
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Create our Render Engine Class
Timer GameTimer;
RenderEngine Renderer;
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Create our Audio Class
Audio* audio;
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//Ensure the class is empty for use...
ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));

//Initialize the Struct
wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
wc.hInstance = hInstance;
wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
wc.lpszClassName = L"WIndowClass1";

//Regist the Window Class
RegisterClassEx(&wc);

//Create the windows and use the result as the handle
hWnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL,
                      L"GSP420 WindowClass",    //Name of the Window Class
                      L"GSP420 Project",        //Title of the Window
                      WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,      //Window style
                      300,                      //x-position of the Window
                      300,                      //y-position of the Window
                      SCREENWIDTH,              //Width of the Window
                      SCREENHEIGHT,             //Heigt of the Window
                      NULL,                     //There is no parent window
                      NULL,                     //No menus are being used
                      hInstance,                //The application handle
                      NULL);                    //We're not using Multiple-Windows

//Display the Window
ShowWindow(hWnd, nShowCmd);

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Setup and Initialize Direct3D
Renderer.initD3D(hWnd);
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Setup and Initialize DirectSound
OutputDebugStringA("BEGIN: AudioInit");
audio = new Audio;
audio->AudioInit(hWnd);
OutputDebugStringA("\nCOMPLETE: AudioInit\n");
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//Enter the main loop

//Windows Event Message Struct
MSG msg;

//Enter our Loop
while (TRUE)
{
    while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        //Translate keystrokes into the correct format
        TranslateMessage(&msg);

        //Send the messages to WindowProc
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    //If the message is WM_QUIT, exit the loop
    if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
        break;

    ////////////////////////////////////
    ////////RUN OUR GAME CODE HERE//////
    ////////////////////////////////////
    GameTimer.calculateTime();

    Renderer.renderFrame();
    ////////////////////////////////////
    ////////RUN OUR GAME CODE HERE//////
    ////////////////////////////////////
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Clean up DirectX and COM
Renderer.cleanD3D();

//Return this part of the WM_QUIT message to Windows
return msg.wParam;
}

//Main Message Handler for the Program
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
//Sort through and find the code to execute 
switch (message)
{
    //This message is read when the window is closed
    case WM_DESTROY:
    {
        //Close the application
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }break;
}

//Handle any messages the switch statement didn't
return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

And for reference the entire InitDSound method

```
bool Audio::InitDSound(HWND hwnd)
{
HRESULT r;                                                  // Create result variable
DSBUFFERDESC bufferDesc;
WAVEFORMATEX wavFormat;

r = DirectSoundCreate8(NULL, &DSound, NULL);                // Initialize DSound
if (FAILED(r))                                              // Check result, break if initialization failed
{
    _com_error error(r);
    LPCTSTR errText = error.ErrorMessage();
    OutputDebugString(errText);
    return false;
}
OutputDebugStringA("\nCOMPLETE: DSound Stage 1 ");

r = DSound->SetCooperativeLevel(hwnd, DSSCL_PRIORITY);      // No idea, allows the format of the primary buffer to be modified
if (FAILED(r))                                              // Check result, break if that thing didnt work
{
    _com_error error(r);
    LPCTSTR errText = error.ErrorMessage();
    OutputDebugString(errText);
    return false;
}
OutputDebugStringA("\nCOMPLETE: DSound Stage 2 ");

//////////////////////////////////
// Primary Buffer Descritpion
//////////////////////////////////
bufferDesc.dwSize = sizeof(DSBUFFERDESC);
bufferDesc.dwFlags = DSBCAPS_PRIMARYBUFFER | DSBCAPS_CTRLVOLUME;
bufferDesc.dwBufferBytes = 0;
bufferDesc.dwReserved = 0;
bufferDesc.lpwfxFormat = NULL;
bufferDesc.guid3DAlgorithm = GUID_NULL;

r = DSound->CreateSoundBuffer(&bufferDesc, &pBuffer, NULL); // Get control of the primary sound buffer on the sounde device
if (FAILED(r))                                              // Check result, break if that failed
{
    _com_error error(r);
    LPCTSTR errText = error.ErrorMessage();
    OutputDebugString(errText);
    return false;
}
OutputDebugStringA("\nCOMPLETE: DSound Stage 3 ");

//////////////////////////////////
// Primary Buffer Format
// (WAV @44,100 16bit stereo)
//////////////////////////////////
wavFormat.wFormatTag = WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;
wavFormat.nSamplesPerSec = 44100;
wavFormat.wBitsPerSample = 16;
wavFormat.nChannels = 2;
wavFormat.nBlockAlign = (wavFormat.wBitsPerSample / 8) * wavFormat.nChannels;
wavFormat.nAvgBytesPerSec = wavFormat.nSamplesPerSec * wavFormat.nBlockAlign;
wavFormat.cbSize = 0;

r = pBuffer->SetFormat(&wavFormat);                         // Set the primary buffer format
if (FAILED(r))                                              // Check result, break if that failed
{
    _com_error error(r);
    LPCTSTR errText = error.ErrorMessage();
    OutputDebugString(errText);
    return false;
}
OutputDebugStringA("\nCOMPLETE: DSound Stage 4 ");

return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On Windows Vista or later, there's no primary buffer anyhow and it's all emulated through WASAPI. The driver determines the output rate and it's always converted to `float` values anyhow. You should just stick with using `DSSCL_NORMAL` because it doesn't really mean anything, and the primary buffer's format is irrelevant.

Unless you are targeting Windows XP, you should avoid using DirectSound which hasn't been updated in 16 years. Look at XAudio2 or 3rd party audio engines like FMOD, Wwise, MSS, OpenAL, etc. all of which implement their own mixers and use WASAPI for final output.